# Maven run multi-module application with Jetty

Tags: java, maven, web-applications, jetty

I have an issue launching my multi-modal application, the application looks like this :

- **Parent/**

  - *pom.xml*
  - **Module1/**

    - *pom.xml*
    - **src/**
    - **target/**
  - **Module2/**

    - *pom.xml*
    - **src/**
    - **target/**

Everything is configured well so that the parent knows the modules, and each module is related to its parent using pom.xml files.

Now when I want to run the whole application I have to go through each module and execute the command **mvn jetty:run** separately.

Is there any way I can do that simply by going to the Parent's folder and doing a single command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution without changing directory - from project root directory, but with command per jetty

### Run jetty from selected module

```
mvn -pl Module1/ jetty:run 
mvn -pl Module2/ jetty:run
```

Used option: `-pl,--projects <arg>`

> > Comma-delimited list of specified
> >                                             reactor projects to build instead
> >                                             of all projects. **A project can be
> >                                             specified by** [groupId]:artifactId or by its **relative path**.

### Run jetty from specified `pom.xml` - alternative version

```
mvn -f Module1/pom.xml jetty:run 
mvn -f Module2/pom.xml jetty:run
```

Used option: `-f,--file <arg>`

> > Force the use of an alternate POM
> >                                             file (or directory with pom.xml).

In general `module` is not a separete application, but part of application (libraries, commons etc). In this case one `jetty:run` is required by project.

Answer (score 2):

Are you working on a Linux / Unix shell based environment?

On the shell (in directory parent) you could try the following command:

```
find ./ -name pom.xml | grep -E "Module1|Module2" | xargs -n 1 -P 10 mvn jetty:run -f
```

Comment: Thanks, I created a shell file to do that :)